# Rigorous Limit Derivation of Kepler's Second Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, resource-recommendations

I'm wondering if anyone can provide me with a more rigorous derivation of Kepler's second law. I looked this up online and couldn't find anything more rigorous than the usual. I'm reading Taylor's *Classical Mechanics* and he quotes the usual derivation whereby,
$$ \frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{v}|$$

and using that this cross product is constant for orbit under a central force.

I'm looking for a resource that shows exactly how and why we can approximate any arbitrary sector swept out from $\mathbf{r}$ to $\mathbf{r+dr}$ with a triangle in the limit.

Comment: Have you taken a calculus course? Did you learn about calculating the area under a curve using infinitesimal rectangles?

Comment: Note that on Phys.SE it is preferred to ask the physics question directly rather than ask for res. recom. It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Edited, my bad. I only asked for a resource so as to spare a long-winded answer to something that has doubtless been explained somewhere but I now understand that is not preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to calculate the area swept out by a particle between time $0$ and $T$.  The natural choice for a question like this would be polar coordinates (in the plane of the motion), so let $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ be the radial and angular coordinates, respectively.  In this language, $|\mathbf r \times \mathbf v| = r^2 \dot \theta$.

First, the area swept out between $t=0$ and $t=T$ is

$$A(T) = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2}r(t)^2 \dot \theta(t) dt$$

and so, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\lim_{T\rightarrow 0} \frac{A}{T} = \lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\frac 1T\int_0^T \frac{1}{2}r(t)^2 \dot \theta(t) dt = \frac{1}{2}r(0)^2 \dot\theta(0)$$

---

Note that the triangle made by connecting $r(0)$ and $r(T)$ has area 
$$\Delta A = \frac{1}{2} r(0) r(T) \sin(\Delta \theta)$$
where $\Delta \theta  = \int_0^T \dot \theta(t) dt$.  Dividing by $T$, 
$$\frac{\Delta A}{T} = \frac{1}{2} r(0) r(T) \frac{\sin(\Delta \theta)}{T}$$

Since $\theta(t)$ is analytic, it follows that $\Delta \theta = \dot \theta(0) T + T^2g(T)$ for some analytic function $g(T)$.  Furthermore,

$$\frac{\sin(\Delta \theta)}{T} = \frac{\sin\big(\dot \theta(0) T +  T^2g(T)\big)}{T}$$
$$ = \frac{\sin\big(\dot \theta(0) T\big)\cos\big(T^2 g(T)\big)}{T} + \frac{\cos\big(\dot\theta(0)T\big) \sin\big(T^2g(T)\big)}{T}$$

Using the standard limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} = a$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(bx^2)}{x} = 0$, we have that

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow 0 } \frac{\sin(\Delta \theta)}{T} = \dot\theta(0)$$

and so

$$\left.\frac{dA}{dt}\right|_{t=0} = \lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta A}{T} =\frac{1}{2} r(0)^2 \dot \theta(0)$$

The same argument holds for every $t$, not just $t=0$.  Therefore, we have that in the limit as $T\rightarrow 0$, the area of the triangle connecting $r(t)$ and $r(t+T)$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}r(t)^2\dot\theta(t)T = \frac{1}{2}\big|\mathbf r(t)\times\mathbf v(t)\big|T$.

---

Comment: Thanks! Is the capital $T$ supposed to be there in the last equality (last line of the post)?